# VSCode & TFS 2015 (GIT) - Linking Commits with Work Items

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-code

The topic is obvious. We use TFS 2015 and our projects are in TFS's GIT Source Control. I would like to link TFS Work Items (PBIs) to the commits I make, from VSCode (Like I can from Visual Studio).

Is there a native support or an extension for this purpose?
I couldn't find much googling. I would appreciate if you share your experiences on this subject.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just have to add `#PBI_Id` (ex. `#1534`) in your commit message. Or do you want an extension to help you easily find the ID of PBI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use #ID on the commit message to link to work items, but before you use it you need to check if it's enable in your TFS:

Go to `http://<TFSinstance>/tfs/<Collection>/<TeamProject>/_admin/_versioncontrol`,
then select your repo, and switch to the *Options* tab. Make sure the appropriate checkmark is ON.

[image]

If you want something visualize, you can install [Azure Repos](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) extension, one of the features is:

> `team associate work items` – Prompts you to choose a work item that
>   is assigned to you (or from the results of your custom query).
>   Choosing a work item will add it to the current commit/check-in
>   message.

Comment: Very detailed explanation! Thank you :)